# How to manage contiguous memory chunks in modern C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've been doing some low level C++ programming these days and it involes a lot of memory management issue. For example, I may need to maintain a chunk of contiguous memory:

```
char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(char)*512*1024));
....
do_something(ptr); // pass to other functions
....
do_something(ptr+sizeof(int)*4); // random access may be needed
....
free(ptr);
```

However, many books say that we should avoid using any raw pointer in modern C++ programing and smart pointers are preferred. Thus, what's the best practice for contiguous memory chunk management in modern C++? Should I use something like std::unique_ptr or std::allocator？

Comment: Generally speaking, using a "chunk of contiguous memory" is an implementation choice, not a requirement.    You have described your implementation choice without explaining the requirement (i.e. what you're trying to achieve by using "a chunk of contiguous memory").   Any answer you get will therefore be opinion-based.   Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: Are the books just suggesting that because they assume mistakes will be made if you use raw pointers? If you are doing low level work then the smart pointers kind of defeats the point as they will just be slower

Comment: @asimes `std::unique_ptr` won't be slower than a raw pointer, it is just syntactic sugar that gets stripped away by the compiler.

Comment: The raw pointers are prone to causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and will not give you any exceptions regarding any errors (You have to find out yourself what error is happening in the pointers, like a buffer overflow)... However, a smart pointer is a new variant of pointer for C++ which includes exceptions on errors and *optional usage of delete* (I am talking about [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) here, obviously) to free the pointer... That is, it will dispose *itself* after it is not used anymore in the scope...

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your advice, in my project, the contiguous memory chunk may be used to store some binary data, and it will be passed and processed by other modules/functions in the project.

Comment: @Ruks There is nothing the standard smart pointers do to keep you from causing undefined behaviour with pointers.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes, they *are* pointers, so a clear definition would be that **"they are not standard in C++"** instead of **"prone to causing undefined behavior"**...

Comment: @Ruks Not sure what you are trying to say. I just wanted to make clear that the smart pointers from the standard library won't throw any exceptions. ("a smart pointer is a new variant of pointer for C++ which includes exceptions on errors")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*many books say that we should avoid using any raw pointer in modern C++*"

It is only **owning raw pointers** that should be avoided. In your case you need to `std::free()` the pointer so you **own** it. Therefore you should definitely put it in a `std::unique_ptr` but with a custom deleter to call `std::free()`.

```
// some type aliases to make life shorter...
struct malloc_deleter{void operator()(void* vp) const { std::free(vp); }};
using  malloc_uptr = std::unique_ptr<char, malloc_deleter>;

auto ptr = malloc_uptr(static_cast<char*>(std::malloc(sizeof(char)*512*1024)));
....
do_something(ptr.get()); // pass to other functions
....
do_something(ptr.get()+sizeof(int)*4); // random access may be needed
....
// no need to free, gets done when ptr` goes out of scope.
```

Comment: Is `sizeof(char)` actually needed?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No. I was just copying OPs code with minimal changes.

Comment: Fair enough, I know it doesn't hurt, but `one == one`. It was more for my edification whether it was some bewildering requirement of being paired with a `static_cast` in C++ than anything else.